# How can I use the WikipediaData function to extract certain section information for a list of URL?

Tags: data-acquisition, wikipedia

I am trying to extract data from a list of URLs for Wikipedia articles. At first, I tried parsing the HTML but it was hard to get the required data as the parsing had some problems and was quite problematic. Then I saw Mathematica had a WikipediaData function which can be used to extract data from Wikipedia articles. Still, I am unsure how to extract certain section data for a list of Wikipedia articles. (It can either be a list of URLs or names of articles whichever is more convenient. I am new to Mathematica so I don't know much of the normal stuff. If anyone could help that'd be useful!

Answer (score 2):

the WikipediaData function is very rich in options.  Suggest looking through the documentation page for a few minutes...anyway, the command has a built in property which returns all the outgoing links on the page:

```
 WikipediaData["Mount Everest", "ExternalLinks"]
```

{"https://maps.yandex.com/-/CVgluFYs", 
"http://www.staeudtner.com/allgemein/360-panorama-view-mount-everest-summit/", "http://imagingeverest.rgs.org/Concepts/Imaging_Everest", 
"http://www.viewfinderpanoramas.org/panoramas/ASIA/Everest-North.gif",
"http://www.viewfinderpanoramas.org/panoramas/ASIA/Everest-South.gif",
...